# How to use python with qr scanner devices?

Tags: python, input, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I want to create a program that can read and store the data from a qr scanning device but i don't know how to get the input from the barcode scanner as an image or save it in a variable to read it after with openCV

Comment: QR scanners usually report decoded text data, not image data that can be handled by OpenCV. It is the camera device that notifies image data. You need to understand the characteristics of the device. If the vendor and model information of the device you are going to use is added, it will be easy to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a barcode scanner automatically outputs to the screen, **just like a keyboard** (except really quickly), and there is an end of line character at the end (like and enter). 
Using a python script all you need to do is start the script, connect a scanner, scan something, and get the input (**STDIN**) of the script. If you built a script that was just always receiving input and storing or processing them, you could do whatever you please with the data.

A QR code is read in the same way that a barcode scanner works, immediately outputting the encoded data as text. Just collect this **using the STDIN of a python script and you're good to go!**